# pandas.read_excel() not speed up via "nrows=10"

Tags: python, excel, pandas

With CSV files I sometimes use `nrows=` parameter for debugging purpose and to "speed up" the reading of the file which is an XLSX file.

I tested the same parameter with `pandas.read_excel()` reading an over 400k lines excel file. But reading that file take round about 3 minutes and 20 seconds no matter if I do `nrows=10` or if I don't use `nrows`.

The result is of course only 10 rows.

I assume this is because of fhe Excel-File format where it is not possible to physically skip/ignore lines while reading?

Comment: Is it an .xls or .xlsx file?

Comment: It is an `.xlsx`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing an XLSX file involves opening a ZIP ([OOXML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) documents are zips of XML files), parsing some XML to find out what sheets there are, then parsing the particular sheet's XML and interpreting the contents to figure out the contents of each cell, etc.

That's not quite as straightforward as opening a text file and only reading ten lines.

I might recommend reading the XLS(X) file once into a dataframe, and then e.g. [pickling](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle) that dataframe for subsequent use. If you're feeling fancy, you could write a function that invisibly does that for you (tries to look for a "cached" pickled version of your document(s)).

Comment: I still do it like you recommend. I also was feeling fancy and created and published my little toolbox [`buhtzology`](https://codeberg.org/buhtz/buhtzology). At this time I have to read several excel files with Mio. of lines. I am in the step _before_ the pickeling currently.

Comment: Well, best put some poor computer to work converting those huge Excel files to a better interchange format then, yeah? :)